# Overflow: length too large

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

I'm receiving the error:
`OverflowError: length too large`

I'm trying to read a 24GB csv on this vm that has 30GB memory:
`Linux indexer 3.19.0-59-generic #66~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:27:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

What are my possible solutions? I'm not familiar with size limits in python:

```
csv_file = csv.reader(media.read().splitlines(), delimiter=mapping['delimiter'], quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: Read and process it in chunks. If your requirements don't allow that, import the data into a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `.read().splitlines()` because that will read the entire file into memory in one go and that's too much. The file object `media` is already an iterator of lines as is so `csv.reader` will handle that correctly. Then iterate over the reader and do whatever you need row by row.